# jquery horizontal scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, scroller

i would like to use the scroller of jquery UI : http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll

but with a mouseover event, i looked everywhere, i think i can do it by binding the event, but i dont really know, i need some help.

I found exactly what i want but it's with mootools : http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/03/using-css-and-mootools-to-simulate.html

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[hoverscroll](http://rascarlito.free.fr/hoverscroll/) or [smooth div scroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/) will do the trick