# How to make a horizontal scrollbar with mouseover effects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

Helo to all, i have been searching all over the web for some jquery or javascript tutorial or plugin for a horizontal scrollbar and i have found many of plugin asnd tutorial but not the one i want.

Now im using tinyscroll and i have found it has alot of bugs, can somebody help me with the next effects.

Mouseover: At mouseover at the right or left it scrolls by itself.
Shadow at hiding: When a image hides at the left or right a shadow effect that gives a "it got in the bottom of this layer" effect.
Scrollbar: simple bar that has a 80% opacity
mouse scroll: that mouse scroll can be used with it.

I need something like the movie scroller in this page:

Cuevana.tv

And i know html and css but css -webkit styling can't do this effects.

I really dont have any codes to start with, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this one](http://www.tonylea.com/go/examples/jquery-horizontal-scrollbars/).

It has the horizontal scrollbar and the mouse scroll works.

With css you could get it to look exactly like the one in the link you posted. (positioning the left and right carets up by the image container and etc...)

Comment: I will try to edit this one  for the hoverscroll and the shadow effect so thanks (hope its not to dificult.)

Comment: The plugin seems to have hoverscroll built in (hover over the left/right carets).  I'm a little unclear on your described dropshadow effect but css should cover just about anything you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quoting a good SOF answer here: [jquery horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122635/jquery-horizontal-scroll)

Try hoverscroll jQuery plug-in - http://rascarlito.free.fr/hoverscroll/

Also try Smooth Div Scroll - http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/demo.html

Comment: I still need the bar, and the shadow effect, and i dont think the mousescrollworks

Comment: Yes but y need the all the efects in one:
hover scroll gives the hover effect and smoothdivscroll the mousescroll and bar 

only need one and still the shadow is missing.